# convert object to xml using jackson-dataformat-xml with default values

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-databind

I am using the jackson-dataformat-xml  dependency to convert my object to  xml.
Its initializing the parent class properties to default value in the output xml but properties of nested class is not getting initialized(in the output xml nested class properties are not coming).
Below is the code which  tried ,can anyone pls look into this issue, if am missing something.

Below is my class structure

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class Settings {

    private  SettingsBlock settingsBlock //nested class;
    private int test1=10;
    private int test2;
}
```

below is the nested class

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class SettingsBlock {

    private Boolean block1=true;
    private Boolean block2=;        
}
```

Building the xml

```
class Build XML{

   XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper()
   String xml = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Settings())
}
```

Output I am getting currently

```
<Settings>   
    <test1>1</test1>
    <test2>0</test2>
    <SettingsBlock/>
</Settings>
```

Output which I wanted is

```
<Settings>     
    <test1>1</test1>
    <test2>0</test2>
    <SettingsBlock>
       <block1>true</block1>
       <block2>false</block2>
     <SettingsBlock/>
</Settings>
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

`SettingsBlock` is not instantiated, that's why *jackson* can't get any property of this object! If you want to have the default values of `SettingsBlock`, you have to instantiate it:

```
public class Settings {
  private  SettingsBlock settingsBlock = new SettingsBlock();
  private int test1=10;
  private int test2;
}
```

Comment: this one worked for me
new Settings().toBuilder().
                settingsBlock(new SettingsBlock().toBuilder().build()

Comment: @Basavaraddy These methods were not in your code snippets. I guess the builder methods doing the instatiation of the variables, right? Then you could upvote my answer.

Comment: I am  not using the any methods I have used the Lombok annotation